# if window size is 300x500 then open page else redirect php code

Tags: php, iframe, window, size

I need some php code which has a defined window size, if size is true run the page if not redirect to another page. I will manage the window size using an iframe. Is it possible with php? If not is there another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a little javacript that checks the width and height then sets the document location if it isnt wht you specified, but it is being echoed from php. you can play with the maxheight, max width and url variables.

```
<?php 
 $jssnippet = "<script type='text/javascript'>var width = window.innerWidth; 
 var height= window.innerHeight; 
 var maxheight=480; 
 var maxwidth=360;
 var redirecturl='http://www.xl21.org';
 if((width>maxwidth) && (height>maxheight)){document.location=url; }</script>"; 

echo $jssnippet;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't possibly know the window size.

This is a task for JavaScript.

[Example of getting window size with JS](http://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewport-size-width-and-height-javascript)

Comment: pleas provide me the js script

Comment: there you go, check the answer now

Comment: i con't understand where i defined the window size

Comment: i have no idea about it can you pleas make the code if you have a little time for make it. pleas

Comment: ok its stupid for you but its impotent for me. i'm just request you that if you can't make happy some one pleas don't hear them. sorry not well in English. hop you understand. and i'm not invite you to Answer it. you come your self. bye